# Compute $\partial_t \Gamma_{ij}^k$ under Ricci flow.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

The $g_{ij}$  is Riemannian  metric ,and is solution of $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}g_{ij}(x,t)=-2R_{ij}(x,t)$.
In the below picture , computing the $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Gamma_{jl}^h$.
I think it should has two parts on the red line, but the part of $\frac{1}{2}\partial_tg^{hm}\{...\}$ is missed. Whether it is because we can choice a suitable coordinate make the $g^{hm}=\delta_{hm}$ so, the $\partial_t g^{hm}=0$?

This picture is from 183th page of the [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947)

[image]

Comment: You seem to be asking if this has something to do with whether or not one *can* choose normal coordinates, but according to the first line of the proof, this is exactly what is done.

Comment: @fuglede  Is your mean  that the normal coordinate is the coordinate makes that $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$?

Comment: Well, at the origin of the coordinate system, yes, and the first partial derivatives vanish at that point; see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates#Properties).

Comment: But if so ,the right part above of the red line will vanish too.

Comment: Hm, no, since again, those properties only hold at a point. It's similar to how you do not have $f''(x) = (f'(x))'$.

Comment: I can't understand you , no matter it hold at  a point or all point ,there is contradiction. If $\partial_t g_{ij}\neq 0$, then $\partial_t g^{ij}\neq 0$,so , there also lack some part above  the red line .

Comment: But say that $\partial_t g_{ij} = 0$ at the point $x = 0$, in our normal coordinate system. Then this does not say much about the value of $\partial_t g_{ij}$ at nearby points, so that in particular, the positional partial derivatives of $\partial_t g_{ij}$ could be non-zero.

Comment: It's product rule again, $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac 12 g^{kl} ( \partial_j g_{il}+ \partial _i g_{jl} - \partial _l g_{ij})$, So $\partial _t \Gamma_{ij}^k= \frac 12 \partial_t g^{il} ( \partial_j g_{il}+ \partial _i g_{jl} - \partial _l g_{ij}) + \frac 12 g^{il} \partial_t(\cdots)$. But the first term is zero at $x$ as $\partial_k g_{ij}$ = 0 at $x$ for all $i, j, k$.

Comment: It's Ricci flow: how would it be possible that $\partial_t g_{ij} = 0$?

Comment: @fuglede    Sorry, I confuse the $\partial _t$ and $\partial_i$

Comment: @JohnMa  Sorry, I confuse the $\partial _t$ and $\partial_i$